# admin/catalog_category/index very slow, large catalog of 20,000 skus

Tags: admin, performance, sql

We currently have an issue on a site where certain admin requests are taking upwards of 40 seconds to complete. It has a large amount of SKUs (22,000), 1 store and also a number of custom modules.

The front end of the site is nice and responsive, as is most of the admin panel. The problem is that any requests that require catalog related lookups show a very long response time. For example the following action:

admin/catalog_category/index = 40+ secs

I understand that the catalog size means expensive SQL joins. Server hardware doesn't seem to be a bottleneck with CPU and memory usage looking reasonable.

SQL query caching is showing a high hit rate.

My question is:

Is there anything that can be done to work around this kind of problem short of rewriting Magento's catalog DB schema? How do other really large sites address this kind of issue? Is this just something that needs to be put up with given the catalog size?

Comment: James are you able to re-index at the command line?

Comment: Yes, I am able to index from CLI but aside from indexes the admin is genrally slow.

Comment: Any update? Were you ever able to profile and find the issue?

Answer (score -1):

22,000 skus is not very large however it comes down to both business and technology factors including amount of code, types of extensions, tier pricing, options, hosting architecture, and more. Large sites use server clusters, even though the frontend is responsive you may be providing static content (fpc for example), however Google, visitor checkouts, admin will for all intents look at the dynamic content. We were running 250,000+ products on a small cluster with no backend performance issues. There is either something in your hosting architecture or in the your install (upgrade, extension) that is causing this. Normally debugging this is time consuming from disabling all third party extensions to a migration to a new install.

Comment: Hi @Serpyre is the only way to achieve good speeds in the admin area to use a server cluster? We have 140,000 active products and are experiencing major issues indexing on our dedicated server. It is a very high spec server, but just a single server. We were hopeful we could get up to 500,000 active products on this server before moving to a server cluster, but maybe not?

Comment: I don't think adding server infrastrucure helps for my particular situation. We have experimented with adding a great deal more hardware using AWS and only saw marginal performance improvements. As I stated frontend speed can be vastly improved through caching but I am talking specifically about admin speed, particularly when working with the catalog (managing categories / product catalog) Has anyone experimented with creating custom indexers or flat tables for use in the admin?